# Key in associative array exists or not

Tags: php, netbeans

I wrote some PHP code to retrieve some data from my MySQL database.

My NetBeans debugger (v7.4) shows all array elements and related keys (of $data_array_from_db) which keys corresponds with the column fields in a the database table, EXCEPT the keys of which database fields are not filled (value NULL).

However, when the array_key_exists() function is executed in the code below for say 'akey' that corresponds with such non filled database field, array_key_exists() returns a 'true' value (instead of expected false) - as if the key does exist (while again, the NetBeans debugger does not show the $data_array_from_db['akey']).

I know for sure that the database function array_key_exists() works correctly. Am I interpreting something wrong? Does/should the key exist if its corresponding database value is NULL?

```
$data_array_from_db = $corpdb->GetSpecificDBRecords($sqlquery5); //GetSpecificDBRecords() includes some PDO statements
if (array_key_exists('akey', $data_array_from_db)) { // Database value is optional; exists?
  $response_array[0]['akey'] = $data_array_from_db['akey']; // This line executed while akey does not show in NetBeans debuggers
}
else { // Database value does not exist; set to 0
  $response_array[0]['akey'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: A print_r or var_dump of $data_array_from_db would be useful...

Comment: Yeah, it exists and its value is `NULL`... You should also check the value

Comment: from the manual itself (http://us3.php.net/array_key_exists) : Note:

For backward compatibility reasons, array_key_exists() will also return TRUE if key is a property defined within an object given as array. This behaviour should not be relied upon, and care should be taken to ensure that array is an array.

To check whether a property exists in an object, use property_exists().

Comment: do a `var_dump($data_array_from_db)` and see what shows up in there.Given you're getting this from a db, then it makes sense that fields with null values would still have a corresponding key available.

Comment: thnx for all comments (!) I just used var_dump and it does indeed show the keys. I'm still wondering why netbeans does not show those particular keys (??)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is a value, and you need to check for it if you want to replace it. Change:

```
if(array_key_exists('akey',$data_array_from_db) ){
```

To:

```
if(array_key_exists('akey',$data_array_from_db) && !is_null($data_array_from_db['akey'])){
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just check if it exists and it's not empty:

```
if (!empty($data_array_from_db['akey'])) {
```